# Getting the dl element to recognise its dt element contents

Tags: html, css

I have two the following CSS code:

```
dl.set {
    position: relative;
}

dl.set dt {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
<dl class="set">
    <dt><img src="images1.jpg" /></dt>
    <dt><img src="images2.jpg" /></dt>
    <dt><img src="images3.jpg" /></dt>
</dl>
```

My aim is to *arrange the images to sort of overlap each other in different positions*. So what I thought I could do is to make use of the `top` and `bottom` attributes of an `absolute` position to arrange their positions.

The `dl` element, however, doesn't recognise the `dt` element contents inside it. The height of the box of the `dl` element remains as `0px`. I tried to give the `dl` element a `overflow: hidden` to clear the float but it also *doesn't* work. Instead, it clips the `dt` elements off.

How can I get the `dl` element to recognise and expand its size according to the size of the contents of the `dt` elements accordingly, while keeping their position `relative` and `absolute` relationship (because I need to position the elements differently)?

Comment: Absolute positioning != floating

Comment: Do you have an example to view your problem? Maybe there are other ways to do it.

Comment: @Paul I have edited my question with a HTML example of what I am trying to achieve. My aim is to arrange the images in the `dl` element to sort of overlap each other in different positions. So what I thought I could do is to make use of the top and bottom attributes of an absolute position to arrange their positions. But of course, it turns out that the `dl` element is not sensing its absolute dt elements.

Answer (score 0):

`absolute` positioning moves an element out of the normal flow. Thus, your `dl` is so-to-say empty, the `dt` is in another layer.

If you position the `dt` absolute, `dl` will never expand to the `dt`'s size (automatically). You'll need to restructure your HTML/CSS or come up with a javascript solution.